# How to properly set a different formatter for a specific logger's child?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

For certain modules or functions, I want to have a different format for the logged messages. I have done this in a way that looks a bit hacky: I have set a special Logger, containing a special Handler, that has the right Formatter.

Here is a simplified portion of my configuration file:

```
formatters:
    dbgMessageFormatter:
        format: '[%(name)s] %(message)s'
    rawMessageFormatter:
        format: '%(message)s'

handlers:
    debugHandler:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: dbgMessageFormatter
    rawHandler:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: rawMessageFormatter

loggers:
    dbg:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: [debugHandler]
    raw:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: [rawHandler]
```

The "main" debugging logger is loaded this way:

```
with open(logging_conf_filename) as f:
    logging.config.dictConfig(yaml.load(f))
dbg_logger = logging.getLogger("dbg")
```

And for a child (named `child` in the snippet below) of this "dbg" logger, I set the other Handler this way:

```
raw_logger = logging.getLogger("raw")
l = logging.getLogger(child)
l.addHandler(raw_logger.handlers[0])
l.propagate = False
```

Is there a better, more straightforward way to set this up?